# Is there a way to see vertex weights of selected bones in pose mode?

Tags: bones, weight-painting, pose-mode, vertex-weights

The vertex painting view is nice for seeing how a vertex is affected by bones at a glance, but I can't figure out how to enable it within pose mode.  Is there a way to do that so that I can see a bone's influence over a mesh when the bone is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your armature, shift select your object, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, your armature will automatically switch to *Pose* mode, you can select the bone you want to see its vertex group. You can enable the *Vertex Selection* option to work on the vertices you want:

[image]